# Is it correct to say "files from 3 days ago" or "files of 3 days ago"?

Tags: american-english

The situation may be as follows:

A computer crashed on 12 January 2020, but we need to get some files as the status on 9 January 2020.

> We need the files from 3 days ago.
>
> We need the files of 3 days ago.

Are they both correct?

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: For example, you modified a file on 01/10/2020 and 01/12/2020, but you are not satisfied with its current status. You want to change the file back to what it was 3 days ago, namely 01/09/2020.

Comment: Ok. I'll be thinking of an answer

Comment: In terms of English it's fine to say "the file from three days ago" (or "the version of X from three days ago" if you're referring to an older version of a current file). But if getting it involves asking someone else for it it is probably more practical to refer to it as "the file from 1/9/2020”, to avoid any misunderstandings if the other person doesn't get a chance to look for it the same day you asked.

Comment: Yes, “from” works best. But also consider using a word more specific to the situation like “files modified three days ago” or “files changed three days ago” or “files as they were three days ago” (it’s difficult because you still haven’t communicated to us the precise meaning you need).

Comment: Definitely "from three days ago". As you are restoring the files from the backup (and originally that would have been from a specific removable medium such as a backup tape) you are "fetching" the file "from" a three day old backup and, when all backups were made to removable media that would have involved literally fetching the the physical medium from the store. The backup may now be to the cloud but the terminology is embedded in everyday speech.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you've depicted has some grammatical issues, so I can't quite grasp the context, but I will do my best. I'm assuming the situation is that a computer no longer works, and it contains data(files) that needs to be accessed?

Your answer would be: "We need to get the status files on the computer from 3 days ago."

Comment: How about this description? For example, you modified a file on 01/10/2020 and 01/12/2020, but you are not satisfied with its current status. You want to change the file back to what it was 3 days ago, namely on 01/09/2020.